# How to test a Windows application on multiple OS versions

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I've developed my Winform applications with VS2010 and run on Win7 OS but I want to test or run it on all the major windows OS like XP, Vista, Windows 7 & Windows 8 and also Windows 2008/2012 server etc.

The easy things come to my mind that I can install all the OS in multiple PC and test my apps in all the PC but this process is time consuming.

So I'd like to know in real life how any good software company test their apps on multiple win OS before release. Do tools exist which can help me or make the job easier?

Comment: A complementary question may be, why would .NET application perform different under different OS systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use virtual machines with different OS. You'll need a big hdd and vmware player, for example. Its free for non-commercial use. And of course, OS images to install. On windows 8 pro you can use HyperV, but I haven't yet tried it.

Answer (score 4):

If you were to try and test in multiple windows versions, your best bet would be to run virtual machines using software like VMware.

Answer (score 2):

.NET is an abstraction layer between OS and your application. You should not be too worried about how its working on different version of Windows.

If you have some IO related functionality in your software, its smart to install software under users own folder to minimize risks of security issues. Also use only files under applications installation root folder.

In my experience companies usually have few virtual machines for major OS versions and they basically execute manual testing for critical functionality.